# Visual studio 2010 CUDA 4.0 Linker errors

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, cuda

Does any one know an easy way to fix the followoing errors:

```
1>matrixmul.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_cutComparefe referenced in function main
1>matrixmul.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_cutDeleteTimer referenced in function main
1>matrixmul.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_cutGetTimerValue referenced in function main
1>matrixmul.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_cutStopTimer referenced in function main
1>matrixmul.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_cutStartTimer referenced in function main
1>matrixmul.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_cutCreateTimer referenced in function main
1>matrixmul.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_cutReadFilei referenced in function main
1>matrixmul.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_cutReadFilef referenced in function "int __cdecl ReadFile(struct Matrix *,char *)" (?ReadFile@@YAHPEAUMatrix@@PEAD@Z)
1>matrixmul.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_cutWriteFilef referenced in function "void __cdecl WriteFile(struct Matrix,char *)" (?WriteFile@@YAXUMatrix@@PEAD@Z)
```

I've already tried adding the lib directories in:

```
C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.0\C\common\lib\x64
C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.0\CUDALibraries\common\lib\x64
```

Any help is apreciated

Answer (score 2):

Those symbols look like functions from the "cutil" library which is included with the CUDA SDK, so you ought to make sure that Visual Studio is set up to link against `cutil.lib`.